# Como especificar key en un array javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Debo almacenar un array como el siguiente

```
var costos = [{1:23},{11:35},{3:5}];
```

Lo hago recorriendo una tabla con jquery de esta forma

```
$('#tabla_2 > tbody > tr').each(function() {
                var ind=$('#id',this).text();
                var va=$('#cant',this).val();
                costos.push({ind:va});
            });
```

El problema es que no me almacena el indice, si no que el nombre literal del nombre de la variable ind

```
{"ind":"23","ind":"35","ind":"5"}
```

Como puedo resolverlo?

Comment: podrias cargar parte de tu html ? serviria para ver donde puede estar el error

Comment: La parte del html funciona bien, de echo si con un alert al ver la variable ind retorna el valor que debería mostrar, el problema radica en esta linea costos.push({ind:va}); que en vez de tomar el valor de la variable toma el nombre literal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La solución próxima sería crear el objeto antes de hacer el push al array para poder especificar el valor de una variable como clave.

```
var ind=$('#id',this).text();
var va=$('#cant',this).val();
var obj = {};
obj[ind] = va;
costos.push(obj);
```

A partir de ES6 se puede especificar directamente la clave como una variable de la siguiente forma.

```
 costos.push({[ind] : va});
```

Comment: muchas gracias solucionaste mi error